# How to replace date string and parse xml data in python using elementtree?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have  `xml` data that is located at below link. The report gets updated everyday so from the link the only thing that changes is date. I would like to achieve below things

*Note: Below link  and `XML` data is for demo purpose*

**XML Link:**

```
https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%5B10/01/2021%22%7D
```

**XML Data**

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><results exportTime="Date time"><report label="Report Title"><record report_date="10/01/2021" narrative="null"><report label="report label"></report>
```

**Things needed:**
Replace the date in the above link with today's date and see if the today's date matches report_date. If report_date matches with today's date parse today's report else parse yesterday's report. If today_date is not present parse yesterday's report as well.

For replacing the date I have below code, which replaces the date. However, I am not sure how to achieve above thing mentioned in Things needed. I am novice `python` programmer.

Thanks in advance for your time!

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
today1 = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y") #gets today's date
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(1)
yesterday=datetime.strftime(yesterday, '%m/%d/%Y') #gets yesterday's date

url_to_replace="https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%5B10/01/2021%22%7D"
url_to_replace=url_to_replace.replace('10/1/2021',yesterday)
```

Comment: This is a broad question. The Python docs about `ElementTree` contain some examples how to navigate through an XML document to find what you need.

Comment: Please post XML that is **well-formed**. In your sample there are end tags missing and the XML declaration is bad (because of the backslashes). Please ask about one specific, reproducible problem at a time.

Comment: you can use `url` with `'%m/%d/%Y` directly in `strftime`. Because `%` has special meaning in `strftime` so it may need to use `%%` instead of `%` in url for `%%5B`, etc. `yesterday.strftime("https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%%5B%m/%d/%Y%%22%%7D")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to replace it - you can use `strftime` with full `url` and with `%m/%d/%Y` in this url.

Because `%` has special meaning in `strftime` so it needs double `%%` in `%%5B` and `%%22%%7D`

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)

url = yesterday.strftime("https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%%5B%m/%d/%Y%%22%%7D")

print('    today:', today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
print('yesterday:', yesterday.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')) 
print('      url:', url)
```

Result:

```
    today: 10/06/2021
yesterday: 10/05/2021
      url: https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%5B10/05/2021%22%7D
```

OR you could use `f-string` to put date in correct place

```py
yesterday_str = yesterday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
url = f"https://www.mywesbite.com/report/%5B{yesterday_str}%22%7D"
```

---

Add here example code which gets `report_date` from `xml`

```py
data = b'''<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
<results exportTime="Date time">
<report label="Report Title">
<record report_date="10/01/2021" narrative="null">
<report label="report label">
</report>
</record>
</report>
</results>
'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

root = ET.fromstring(data)

report_date = root.find('.//record[@report_date]')

if report_date:  # if not None then get attribue                         
    report_date = report_date.attrib['report_date']

today_str = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print('report_date:', report_date)
print('      today:', today_str)
print('   the same:', report_date == today_str)

if report_date == today_str:
    print("parse today's report")
else:
    print("parse yesterday's report")
```

Result:

```
report_date: 10/01/2021
      today: 10/06/2021
   the same: False

parse yesterday's report
```

Comment: Thank you! How should I approach if report_date matches with today's date parse today's report else parse yesterday's report ? If today_date is not present parse yesterday's report as well ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want but in last line of example you have `report_date == today_str` which you can use with `if/else` - `if report_date == today_str: ... else: ...`

Comment: So I think what I need to do is to run Element tree before If/else statement get report_date then use if/else statement as you suggested. If report_Date==today then It should parse today's report. Else, it will parse yesterday's report. However, the only thing I am missing is what if my xml doesn't contain report_date tag ? in that case it should parse yesterday's report as well.Hope it's clear! Is it something doable ?

Comment: if there is no `report_date` then `root.find('.//record[@report_date]')` should give `None` and then you should skip `.attrib['report_date']`. Line `if report_date == today_str:... else:...` should runs `else` when `report_date` is `None`. I add this to example in answer.